# How do I setup my blog so the size of each element is specified?

Tags: html, layout, structure, css

I'd like my webpage to look like this however I am unsure of the way I would go about restricting each element i.e. title, content, navigation and footer so they arrange like shown in the image below?

Would I specify the max-width etc?

[image]

Comment: You can design this by taking table and specifying width for columns and colspan property

Comment: There are **a lot* of ways to skin this cat. It's important to know what the other requirements for the design are. Among other things it's very important to think about how should it reflow on different screens.

Comment: You *could* design it by making a table. But the web design/ development community has collectively been trying to move *away* from  table-based design for a very long time now. Really, this isn't that hard a layout to do: header and footer divs, left sidebar div, main div. You can specify widths in absolute or percentage units. However, you *should* be thinking about how it'll perform on other screens.

Comment: @LiavK Thanks for replying but would I position the elements so they are fixed as when I attribute widths the footer pushes up so its just below the title? Thanks.

Comment: Hey Issac, sounds like you might be having your divs collapse when using float. Chris Coyer has a nice article on http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ that explains the issue and how to deal with it. If you're impatient, you can just look at KrisRogo's answer below. And, if you really wanted, you *could* do it in a table. But you may also want to understand why people have been trying to kill  table based layout for about 10 years now, first: https://www.google.ca/search?q=why+is+table+based+layout+bad&oq=why+is+table+based+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.6898j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @LiavK Thank you very much, I have now solved the problem thanks to all the help you guys have mentioned! However my footer consists of a list with two items 'name' and 'email' when I float the list to the left the items group on one line, how would I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using divs?

if so:

```
#header{
    width: 100%;
}

#navigation{
    width: 30%; // example
    float: left;
}

#content{
   width: 70%; // example, navigation and content must = 100
   float: left;
}

#footer{
   width: 100%;
}
```

No need to specify min- max- unless you want to make sure that, for example, navigation is 30% of the page's width unless that would make it smaller than 200px, then you would use:

```
#navigation{
    width: 30%; // example
    min-width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but when I do this the footer shifts up, do I position it so that it's fixed at the bottom? Thanks again, even though the question may seem simple.

Comment: By default all elements will go as close to top left corner as that can. Keep in mind that as you add content to the content box, it will grow and push the footer down. If you want play with `position: fixed/static/absolute;` and `bottom: 0px;` to adjust it's position.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have now solved the problem thanks to all the help you guys have mentioned! However my footer consists of a list with two items 'name' and 'email' when I float the list to the left the items group on one line, how would I stop this?

Comment: You can try `text-align: center;`. If that on it's own doesn't help, a popular work around is to have separate divs for general layout, and then divs inside them to hold the actual content, eg. `<div id="FootContainer"><div if="FootContent">your text</div></div>` this will allow to separate setting used to align the boxes with settings used to handle the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
            table
            {
                width: 100%;
                border:1px solid black;
            }
            .col1
            {
                width: 25%;
                border-right:1px solid black;
            }
            .col2
            {
                width: 75%;
            }
            .header
            {
                border-bottom:1px solid black;
            }
            .footer
            {
                border-top:1px solid black;
            }
    </style>

    <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="header">
                    header
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1">
                    col1
                </td>
                <td class="col2">
                    col2
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="footer">
                    footer
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Thanks but I was trying to avoid the use of tables as I will be using one later for a different page. However the info you has given me an idea and will be very useful! Thanks again!